# Google Cloud Functions Custom Log Labels

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know if it's possible to add custom labels to the logs for a python based Google Cloud Function? In the image below, the default labels of function_name and execution_id are present for every log entry. I want something similar for custom labels, so for instance a client_id for every log entry. I've checked the docs and googled this extensively, but am going around in circles.

[image]

Comment: I would guess, there are at least two places, where 'labels' can be recorded  in the log record payload - at the top level - just 'labels' and within the 'resource' struct... The first case - labels are to be provided with each log record (when you do the 'log'), the second case - once the Resource is created, those labels will be provided with each record automatically... Can you describe a bit more - at least is it enough to provide labels every time you do 'log', or you would prefer something more complicated?

Comment: @al-dann thanks, the second case sounds closer to what I am trying to achieve. I would like the labels to provided for each record automatically as you suggest, but it's important that I can set those labels dynamically for each invocation of the function.

Comment: I think [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels#create-label) will help you in creating labels for each log records.

Answer (score 1):

See [Processing special JSON fields in messages](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#processing_special_json_fields_in_messages)

It's slightly confusing and I encourage you to test this to ensure it meets your needs but, if you add e.g. `logging.googleapis.com/labels` (see [special fields](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration#special-fields)) and this is an object e.g `{"foo": "X", "bar": "Y"}` that matches the structure of [labels](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#FIELDS.labels), then your logged entries should include your custom `labels.

I'm using this with Cloud Run from Golang and can attest that it works. I wrote about it [Golang Structured Logging w/ Google Cloud Logging](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/211018/)

Comment: thanks. Unless I am misunderstanding this, the solution you've suggested requires me to explicitly write those logs? I think the Resource setting option al-dann suggested above might be closer to what I am looking for.